# Spring Boot JPA ManyToMany MappingException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities that I want to relate via ManyToMany. I found a lot of examples (like this one https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Example_of_a_ManyToMany_relationship_annotation or https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) and even have another place in my code where a ManyToMany relationship seems to work, but still I can't figure this one out so far.

[image]

I'm getting the following exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKru66hm0369ayn8dvjj2rgxr9v:user_role [role_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (user_role [user_id,role_id])

Class User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Class Role

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Comment: You mapped the entity Role to the table user_role (i.e. the join table) instead of the table role.

Comment: In case you don't quite understand what JB Nizet is trying to say: Change `@Table(name = "user_role")` to `@Table(name = "role")` in your Role class. Currently you have mapped 2 tables to the same table name (The table for role and the join table of the manytomany relation) which will create quite some mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this link](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-using-annotations-1.html)!

Anyways, the problem is that you have the Class Role

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class Role {
```

and also in the Class User

```
 @JoinTable(
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
```

Both the places, name of table is same...
That must be the cause of error...